# How to visualize kmeans clustering on multidimensional data

Tags: python, visualization, k-means

I am using kmeans clustering algorithm on mnist dataset and want to visualize the plots after clustering. So far I did this

```
from mnist import MNIST

mndata = MNIST('Datasets')
X_train, y_train = mndata.load_training()

#do the clustering
k_means = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=len(np.unique(y_train)))
k_means.fit(X_train)
labels = k_means.labels_
```

So, I now have 10 clusters representing 0 to 9. How can I visualize these clusters?

Answer (score 13):

You can visualise multi-dimensional clustering using pandas plotting tool parallel_coordinates.

```
predict = k_means.predict(data)
data['cluster'] = predict
pandas.tools.plotting.parallel_coordinates(data, 'cluster')
```

Comment: We should use: `pandas.plotting.parallel_coordinates(data,'cluster')` , since `plotting` is out of  `tools`.

Comment: what is cluster in data['cluster']?

Comment: 'Cluster' is name of new column that is being added to dataframe named 'data'. This column will contain cluster labels such as 0,1,2... as predicted by K-Means.