# plot kmeans clustering on more than 2 dimensional data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataset with 6 columns and after using KMEANs I need to visualize the plot after clustering. I have six clusters. how can I do it?
this my Kmeans clustering code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_features = scaler.fit_transform(psnr_bitrate)
kmeans = KMeans(init="random",n_clusters=6,n_init=10,max_iter=300,random_state=42)
kmeans.fit(scaled_features)
y_kmeans = kmeans.predict(scaled_features)
```

I found another post on this link:
[How to visualize kmeans clustering on multidimensional data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46844654/how-to-visualize-kmeans-clustering-on-multidimensional-data)
but I could not understand the solution, because I do not know what is

```
cluster
```

in that code?!

I used the following code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn import cluster

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_features = scaler.fit_transform(psnr_bitrate)
kmeans = KMeans(init="random",n_clusters=6,n_init=10,max_iter=300,random_state=42)
kmeans.fit(scaled_features)
y_kmeans = kmeans.predict(scaled_features)
scaled_features['cluster'] = y_kmeans
pd.tools.plotting.parallel_coordinates(scaled_features, 'cluster')
```

and it produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-77-2e66d8a57100>", line 7, in <module>
    scaled_features['cluster'] = y_kmeans

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

my input data for clustering is a numpy variable like this:

```
31.764833 35.632833 38.088500 39.877250 41.331917 42.923750
29.832750 34.567500 37.527417 39.621000 41.412583 43.023917
36.777167 41.151333 44.122500 46.237167 47.879083 49.832250
46.871500 52.006333 54.784583 57.099417 58.767833 60.674667
```

it has 6 columns and 1301 rows. but my columns does not have name.

Comment: `cluster` in that code corresponds to `from sklearn import cluster`

Comment: no, I thnik this is not true. because in the answer code we have this: from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_features = scaler.fit_transform(psnr_bitrate)
kmeans = KMeans(init="random",n_clusters=6,n_init=10,max_iter=300,random_state=42)
kmeans.fit(scaled_features)
y_kmeans = kmeans.predict(scaled_features)
scaled_features['cluster'] = y_kmeans
pd.tools.plotting.parallel_coordinates(scaled_features, 'cluster')

Comment: and cluster is used as a column I think

Comment: Yes, the string `"cluster"` is used as a column name of a pandas dataframe in the solution. I still don't get what you don't understand...

Comment: I used the code I am putting above and using cluster produces an error. please see the above I added the new code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points, it should be `pd.plotting.parallel_coordinates` for later versions of [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.plotting.parallel_coordinates.html) , and it is easier if you make your predictors a data frame, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

# import some data to play with
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_features = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(X))
```

If you can, give column names:

```
scaled_features.columns = iris.feature_names
```

Kmeans and assign cluster:

```
kmeans = KMeans(init="random",n_clusters=6,n_init=10,max_iter=300,random_state=42)
kmeans.fit(scaled_features)

scaled_features['cluster'] = kmeans.predict(scaled_features)
```

Plot:

```
pd.plotting.parallel_coordinates(scaled_features, 'cluster')
```

[image]

Or do some dimension reduction on your features and plot:

```
from sklearn.manifold import MDS
import seaborn as sns

embedding = MDS(n_components=2)
mds = pd.DataFrame(embedding.fit_transform(scaled_features.drop('cluster',axis=1)),
             columns = ['component1','component2'])
mds['cluster'] = kmeans.predict(scaled_features.drop('cluster',axis=1))

sns.scatterplot(data=mds,x = "component1",y="component2",hue="cluster")
```

[image]

Comment: is it a way to show the cluster's center on these plots using parallel corodinate?

Comment: could you please tell me is any way to show the cluster centers on your plot you draw above? because you use this pd.plotting.parallel_coordinates(scaled_features, 'cluster')
 for plotting and I do not know how can I show cluster centers on this plot too.

Comment: I can try later, right now tied up with work

Answer (score 0):

`scaled_features` is a numpy array, you cannot index an array with a string. You need to convert it first to a dataframe with this:

```py
scaled_features = pd.DataFrame(scaled_features)
```